# HAProxy random Empty Response

Tags: haproxy

I installed a HAPROXY for balance between two servers. Unfortunately the HAPROXY return random ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I installed the stats also but the stats does not appear *frequently* because sometimes the stats is shown. I double check with some friends my configuration and I did not found problems.

```
defaults
    timeout connect 3000ms
    timeout server 10000ms
    timeout client 10000ms

global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

frontend stats
    bind *:1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth user:password

frontend http_in
    bind *:80
    acl is_audio hdr_end(host) -i subdomain.myserver.com
    acl is_proxystats hdr_end(host) -i stats.myserver.com
    use_backend srv_audio if is_audio
    use_backend srv_stats if is_proxystats
#    acl url_blog path_beg /blog
#    use_backend blog_back if url_blog
    default_backend srv_audio

backend srv_audio
    balance roundrobin
    server audio1 10.10.10.1:80 check
    server audio2 10.10.10.2:80 check

backend srv_stats
    server Local 127.0.0.1:1936
```

My configuration:

- HA Proxy version 1.6.3 (package 1.6.3-1ubuntu0.1 amd64)
- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Cloud Machine on AWS LightSail 512KB RAM
- System with all packages updated.

I already read the answer of similar question at [HAProxy random HTTP 503 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994629/haproxy-random-http-503-errors) and the answer is not the same. As suggested there the command `netstat -tulpn | grep 80` does not show two HAPROXY running:

```
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      -
```

But `ps ax | grep haproxy` returns:

```
22890 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid
22891 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
22894 ?        Ss     0:31 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I dig more into HAProxy and read a lot of tutorials and I believe I found the solution.

I did two changes:

- Changed `hdr_end(host)` to `hdr_dom(host)`
- Added `mode http`to: `frontend http_in`, `backend srv_audio` and `backend srv_stats`

Now, HAPROXY is very stable without bizarre behavior

Comment: I found very useful information here: https://serversforhackers.com/load-balancing-with-haproxy